# the function mysql_result

Tags: php

If there is an error function mysql_result then it returns 0?

I looked everywhere but i could not find an answer ....

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `price` FROM `prices` where bin = 1 limit 0,10" ) ;
    $i=0;
    $d=0;
    while($i!=10){
        $d=$d+mysql_result($result, $i)or die($d);  
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

its returns 7 errors ...

> ( ! ) Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump
>   to row 3 on MySQL result index 5 in C:\wamp\www\fom\Untitled 1.php on
>   line 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `price` FROM `prices` where bin = 1 limit 0,10" ) ;
    $i=0;
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $d=0;
    while($i < $rows && $tmp=mysql_result($result, $i++)){
        $d+=$tmp;
    }
?>
```

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 3 on MySQL result index 5 in C:\wamp\www\fom\Untitled 1.php on line 6
**there is 3 values with bin =3**

Comment: @asafg8, That's a warning not an error. The fact that it didn't work means it returns false and your code will work past it.

Comment: i used mysql_fetch_array

`<?php
    include "config.php";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `price` FROM `prices` where bin = 1 limit 0,10" ) ;
    $i=0;
    $d=0;
    while($tmp=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $d+=$tmp['price'];
    }
    echo $d;
    
?>
`

Comment: @asafg8, Try what I just put.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you shouldn't use mysql_result. It is slower than the other methods.

Try mysql_fetch_array()

prototype:

```
while ($row =
    mysql_fetch_array ($result)){

echo (whatever you want depending upon the index);

}
```

or you can also return it as an array.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove die($d) at line no 7 and check it again.